# Swift: Align view X points from center towards trailing edge

Tags: swift, autolayout, right-to-left

I have a UIImageView which should be placed 10 points from center of the parent UIView. In LTR it works fine but in RTL it should be -10 points.

Is there a way to align X points from center towards trailing edge? Or should I set the constraint manually based on the layout direction?

Comment: Are you sure you want the UIImageView to be at the center of the center based on the UIView, 10 from the left and 10 from the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you constrain the **Leading** anchor of the image view to the **CenterX** anchor of your view, with a `Constant: 10`, it will automatically swap to its **Trailing** anchor at `-10 pts` from the **CenterX**.

Here's how you could do it via code:

```
    let imgView = UIImageView()
    imgView.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
    imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    if let img = UIImage(systemName: "person") {
        imgView.image = img
    }
    view.addSubview(imgView)
    let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 100.0),
        imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0),
        imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor),
        imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor, constant: 10.0),
    ])
```

Here's how it could look in Storyboard (the vertical red line is just a 1-pt wide view showing the horizontal center):

[image]

and at run-time, using RTL language (NO code at all):

[image]

Comment: Yea, probably will go by your suggestion. I currently had image center to view center + 10 constraint. Knowing the width of the image, I can align it by leading to center as you said. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is used when you want to adjust Constrains to code.

You should also add Constrain for the top and bottom.

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

...

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  myImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  myImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
  myImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
  myImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
}
...
```